# simpler query for counting total row in the column

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

not sure if my below query script right to execute as I am trying to find just one query in Oracle SQL query

> select  
> distinct (master_id) , 
> last_name  
> from (
>
> select q2.* , 
> max (count_a) over (partition by master_id)
> count_b 
> from ( select  q1.* , 
> count (*) over (partition by
> master_id order by purchased_date desc ) count_a 
> from profile  q1)
> q2) 
> where count_b > 2

I am trying to minimise timer to execute get data by reducing sub query

for example above it has two subqueries

max (count_a) over (partition by master_id) count_b

count (*) over (partition by master_id order by purchased_date desc ) count_a

so I played around until this query
max (count (*)) over (partition by master_id) count

SQL query script;

> select * 
> from profile a
>
> join( select * from (
>
> select 
> master_id, 
> max (count(*)) over (partition by
> master_id) count 
> from profile)  
> where count >2) b
>
> ON a. master_id = b. master_id

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Could you post sample data and desired result? I don't quite understand what "counting total row in the column" means. Besides, DISTINCT is applied to all columns in SELECT column list, not just MASTER_ID (if that's what your code represents).

Comment: hi @Littlefoot :) I have updated the above hopefully, that makes sense to you. Thank you again for your help!